# how automatically show the image title before the image caption/description in a wordpress gallery?

Tags: images, gallery, title, captions

I am using a simple Wp 5.x gallery like this
[gallery size="full" columns="1" ids="6304,6305,6306,6307,6308,6309"]

The gallery shows me the images and the captions/description after the image. How can I automatically insert/inject the gallery image *title* BEFORE this image *captions/description*?

See image expample attached

Thanks in advance
[image: wp 5.x gallery example]

Answer (score 0):

use this code in `single.php`

```
  $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    )))
    {
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $attachmenturl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
            $attachmentimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, full );
            $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
            $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );
            $i++;
            if (!empty($imageTitle)) {
                echo ' » '.$imageDescription.'';
} else { echo '' ; }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No Image Found';
    }?>
```

Comment: Hi SauRav, thank you very much. I hired a programmer in 2020 to make this for me. But for another gallery I will use your code. Thank you